# Database Design for Point of Sale (itemized and bundled)

Tags: mysql

I was wondering how I could go about implementing tables for this database in the most efficient manner? I am still very new at database design and would like advice on this issue.

I have a table for storing orders - tbl_orders (i left out the unique id for this table)

```
oid     |   pid       
--------+----------+
501          1     
501          2         
501          3
```

I have a table for storing ala-carte products - tbl_products

```
pid |   description         |   amount  
----+-----------------------+-----------+
1      Burger                  5.40        
2      Fries (S)               2.20        
3      Cola (S)                2.00
```

Another for bundled meals - tbl_bundles

```
bid |   description         
----+-----------------------+
1      FISH BURGER MEAL
```

Another table that details what is in each bundled meal - tbl_bundleDetails

```
bdid |   bundle_id  | description |   amount 
-----+--------------+-------------+---------+
1         1            Burger         5.40        
2         1            Fries (S)      2.20        
3         1            Cola (S)       2.00
```

So the idea is that bundles are made out of a combination of items. My current approach is that when a user selects the bundle, a filter on the records in tbl_BundleDetails is done to filter out that particular bundle's ID and these records are selected and duplicated into the order's table.

i.e. A user orders FISH BURGER MEAL (bid: 1) so all records in tbl_BundleDetails with bundle_id = 1 is 'duplicated' into the orders table.

On top of that, if a user needs additional alacarte items, these individual records are simply also duplicated into the orders table directly (individually).

So lets say the user orders 2 FISH burger meals (recorded as oid 501) - and an additional fries alacarte, the below would be the table's result. Ordering via Ala Carte or Bundle results in the same itemized output.

```
oid     |   pid       
--------+----------+
501          1            \
501          2            } INSERT VIA BUNDLE FISH BURGER #1
501          3            /

501          1            \
501          2            } INSERT VIA BUNDLE FISH BURGER #2    
501          3            /

501          2            - Ala Carte Addition of Fries
```

Is there a better method to implement the set of tables in the database?
Would appreciate any advice! Thank you!

Comment: Do prices stay the same? Meaning, if I was to order Burger, Fries  and Cola separately, would I pay the same as if I ordered the FISH BURGER MEAL in the first place? (In your example it looks that way, but then having the amount in tbl_bundles again would be redundant. And description seems to be redundant anyway.)

Comment: yup exactly, all prices remain the same.
it's not exactly redundant because it would be easier to take orders if they are exactly that bundle instead of keying them separately.

- a possible use i could imagine that a line item such as a special may be included in the bundle .. i.e. Bundled Extras such as a freebie (priced at $0) that comes included.  

any advice?

Comment: _“It would be easier”_ does not make it less _redundant_ :-) And JOINing the necessary data to it from the products table, when the bundle table only holds bundle id and product id is easy as well. And your “freebies” [c|s]hould be in the product table as well – with maybe an additional attribute specifying that they should not be shown on the “normal” menu.

Comment: Thanks! This makes alot of sense CBroe!

BTW how about the approach though... any comments? Is duplicating the records into the orders table the way to go?

Comment: Well it’s not really duplicating if you are just inserting the product ids into the order table – and it is one way to go. Disadvantage (maybe), you will not be able to determine later how many customers ordered bundles, and how many ordered the products on their own / advantage (maybe), you can change the contents of a bundle whenever you like (whereas if you were to record the bundle id for an order, you would have to create a _new_ bundle instead to not invalidate your existing order data).

Comment: One thing you could think about changing still, is have your bundles not reside in an extra table, but consider them `products` as well (again, maybe with an additional attribute to differentiate between a bundle and a stand-alone product), and the `pid` from the products table replaces `bdid` and `bundle_id` in the bundle details table then. The amount in the product table could either be left out (NULL), if you want to calculate it from the bundle’s products – or could be used to to set a _different_ price; that way, you could easily implement _discounts_ for your bundles as well …

Comment: Yes I meant inserting :) - BTW, I really appreciate all the help CBroe! I think I have a better idea now to use a single product table and make better of it even for bundle details and forgo the need for a redundant table!